# How to trigger a Javascript function of an HTML page from a WinJS Metro app

Tags: javascript, html, function, winjs

I am developing a Metro app (Javascript) with VS2012 which is invoked via URI from an HTML page loaded in an external web browser by clicking a link:

```
<a href="mymetroapp://">open metro app</a>
```

this is my HTML page

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML page</title>
            <script>
                function x() {
                    alert("my metro app invoked this alert");
                }
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="mymetroapp://">open metro app</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my metro app has this button

```
<button id = "Button2"  class="button" onclick="window.opener.x();">load html function</button>
```

my intention is to show the alert on HTML page called directly from my metro app,

this is for triggering events like data load on my HTML after doing something on my metro app (interaction between webApp and metro apps ) is this possible???

thanks in advance for the support

Comment: Apps can't communicate back and forth like that. It's a "launch and forget".

Comment: Just to expand a bit on what @WiredPrairie said, while native HTML apps in Windows do run a version of the IE rendering (and JavaScript) engines, they are *not* the same application. That is, the HTML and JavaScript you write in your Metro app is *not* running in Internet Explorer properly, thus there can not be any sharing of data between the two.

Comment: maybe in the future it will be possible with a shared worker. but is not supported yet.